# Indexing duplicates python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I use .index in a list it will always return the first element that come up. But what if they were duplicates and I wanted their indexes as well?
For example:

```
listm=["shell","shell","use"]
listm.index("shell")
```

It will return `0` but there are 2 `"shell"`s. How would I get the index of both?

Answer (score 2):

By using a list comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
>>> ind = [i for i, j in enumerate(listm) if j == 'shell']
>>> print(ind)
[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using : `list comprehension` + `enumerate`,

```
In [26]: listm = ["shell","shell","use"]

In [27]: [i for i,j in enumerate(listm) if j == "shell"]
Out[27]: [0, 1]
```