# How to find all occurrences of an element in a multidimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Because .index() always returns the first occurrence of an element I'm struggling to find all the indexes of an element with multiple occurences but in a multidimensional list.
For example:

```
main_list=[["Name1",[21,22,25]],
          ["name2",[25,21,24]],
          ["name3",[29,21,24]]]
```

How would I find all indexes of main_list.index(25)?The search should return the "name1" and "name2"

Comment: How should the "index" look, then? What is the element you are looking for, exactly? A name, or a number, or a sub-list that has a certain name? Please show an example "search query" and the expected result.

Comment: A jagged list does not have dimensions in the conventional sense, so your question is quite unclear.

Comment: What should your search return? `Name1` or `Name1:2`? Also: don't you find the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553638/python-find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list-of-lists) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list) SO thread?

Comment: Wait - you asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202594/indexing-duplicates-python) within 10 minutes?  Why didn't you combine them?